# How to remove the scrollbar in Vmware vm?

Tags: vmware

I was having an issue on the vertical and horizontal scrollbar of VMware. I am using ubuntu and when I enter the full screen mode, the VM was displayed only half of it's screen, and to navigate the next 1/2 I will have to use the vertical and horizontal scrollbar provided by the VM. I tried all options on the display preferences and none of them work. Please help.

Comment: VMware vm? that is not android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be your screen resolution is set too high for your monitor. 
On ubuntu you can adjust this under System -> Preferences -> Display